# oracle group by date with specific time

Tags: oracle, group-by

some will say "another question from that guy" but here is my Problem. all this works as designed:

```
with tab1 as (  
select to_timestamp( '04.02.15 14:25:21.503000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '04.02.15 14:25:25.154000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '09.02.15 22:20:36.861000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '09.02.15 22:20:36.883000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '10.02.15 04:19:13.839000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '10.02.15 04:13:18.142000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '10.02.15 12:43:18.171000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '11.02.15 04:30:53.654000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '11.02.15 22:00:38.951000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '11.02.15 22:00:42.014000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '16.02.15 08:50:43.967000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '16.02.15 16:35:41.387000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '16.02.15 16:35:42.835000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '17.02.15 04:21:08.542000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '17.02.15 04:21:08.912000000' ) as dt from dual union all   
select to_timestamp( '17.02.15 04:06:09.818000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '17.02.15 04:40:39.411000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '18.02.15 04:41:08.218000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '18.02.15 03:20:40.609000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '18.02.15 01:20:40.712000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '20.02.15 06:55:42.185000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '20.02.15 12:55:42.364000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '20.02.15 12:55:42.518000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '20.02.15 12:55:43.874000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '20.02.15 14:16:05.080000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '20.02.15 18:14:17.630000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '22.02.15 21:25:40.683000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '22.02.15 21:25:42.046000000' ) as dt from dual union all  
select to_timestamp( '23.02.15 12:43:27.246000000' ) as dt from dual   
order by dt  
),  
tab2 as(  
select trunc(dt) as leaddate, dt,    
case   
    when dt between (to_timestamp(trunc(dt)) + interval '04:30' hour to minute) and (to_timestamp(trunc(dt)) + interval '28:29' hour to minute) then (dt)   
    else (dt) - interval '04:30' hour to minute       
end as newBaseTime  
from tab1  
)  
select trunc(newBaseTime),  
sum(case when ( dt <= to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(dt)),'dd.MM.yy') + interval '17:30' hour to minute) then 1 else 0 end) as beforeTS,  
   sum(case when ( dt > to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(dt)),'dd.MM.yy') + interval '17:30' hour to minute) then 1 else 0 end) as afterTS  
from tab2  
group by  trunc(newBaseTime)   
order by trunc(newBaseTime)
```

the idea is to Group by days with a "new time base" and check if Dates are before or after a defined daytime. due to contracts days in our company lasts from 4.30a.m. this day to 4.30. next day. my solution above works (with little data), but i guess there is an easier way to get result. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but you seem stuck on this question... perhaps this is the solution you are looking for?

```
select dt, trunc(dt - interval '270' minute) as leaddate from tab1
```

This will preserve the timestamp (showing perhaps "today's" date) but if the time is before 4:30 am, the leaddate will be "yesterday's" date.

If this is NOT what you were looking for, please try to clarify your question.